# How to stop VLC showing video separate from control interface?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player

I'm on macOS 10.14.6 and VLC 3.0.11. A while ago, VLC started showing my videos in a separate borderless window, like this:

[image: separate windows!]

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to configure this so I get the traditional view back, where the control panel is part of the window showing the video. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Possible cause: embedded video is disabled.

Tools (menu) → Preferences → Show Settings: All (bottom left) → Video (left pane) → **Embedded Video**

Enable this option. Save. Restart VLC. Resize the main window if needed.

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I actually had already tried that. However, looking at that page I saw the "Reset Preferences" option and that fixed it! I still don't know what the setting was, but I'm happy to have it working.

Comment: Yes for me also nothing worked and then just hitting "reset all" did the trick

Comment: It was checked. I unchecked it, saved it, then checked it and saved it. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment to Kamil Maciorowski, I managed to fix this by resetting preferences to the defaults using *Preferences | Reset All*.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by resetting all prefs, but it was probably this…

"Show video within the main window" which is on by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same problem in linux，Go to Tools -> Preferences and tick Embedded video and untick Zoom interface to video size selection.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today in Arch Linux.

Resetting my preferences didn't work but turning off "Use only one instance when started from the file manager" scrolling down under the interface settings in the simple settings window did it for me.